# Interpretation of Gargamelle Experiment Photos

Tags: experimental-physics, weak-interaction

I have been trying to understand the Gargamelle experiment, but would like some clarification.

I understand the apparatus is designed to cause charged particles to generate bubbles which are visible on photograph, like a cloud chamber. However, I am confused on the images that come from the experiment.

From what I've read, a neutron beam is fired in the chamber, and the neutrinos will interact with the nuclei of the solvent molecules. The reactions that were predicted to occur were as the right column following image depicts:

[image]

So we expect two cases:

1: Emission of a W boson will correspond to two lines emerging from the invisible neutrino (since the muon and proton are both charged)

2: Emission of a Z boson will correspond to a deflection of the line due to momentum being transferred to the electron (since the neutrino is neutral and the electron is charged). I think it could also correspond to a single line emerging from nowhere (if the electron is initially stationary)

This is how I would interpret a images from the experiment
[image]
[image]

While these make sense given the above interactions, there's other images I can't really reconcile. For example, in the following, how do 3 lines emerge (center left side of the image)?

[image]

I know very little about particle physics but given the interactions above (assuming no others are occurring, at least...) Id imagine we should only expect the two cases I stated above. Is there a problem with my understanding?

Comment: the picture is fig 2 here  https://cerncourier.com/a/gargamelle-the-tale-of-a-giant-discovery/ . there are many more interactions expected " It is a hadronic neutral current event, also sought in the experiment. a neutrino is scattered on a nucleus.

Comment: @annav so would the labelling of the first two figures be correct? and for the image you linked what's being produced? the only interactions I could find were the one in the first image where the Z boson is exchanged between a neutrino/electron, I looked through like 2 papers from CERN and this was the only interaction that was stated as being expected ("event B")--I see in one a reaction of a proton and neutron creating a charged pion and two protons, but im assuming the proton would come from the charged current interaction above and would leave a trail before branching

Comment: it is fig 1 in this https://cerncourier.com/a/neutral-currents-a-perfect-experimental-discovery/

Comment: they do not try to see what particles they are, it is sufficient that they cannot be leptons because of the ionisation of the tracks.